# A word for absolutely predictive

Tags: adjectives

In biology, most things are predictive: Toxicity is given in LD<sub>50</sub>, but one cannot know which half of the population will die, 1% of kids will be born with some type of autism, but we don't know which kids (obviously, there are risk factors, but nothing is absolute), etc....

On the other hand, if I combine water with an acid, it absolutely heats up. If I drop my coffee cup, it's absolutely falling to the floor. (A pedant might mention that the coffee cup doesn't fall in space, but that gets to the heart of the matter - there are preconditions that we understand in physics, but as sciences get softer, those preconditions become less well understood - I assume that as Biology matures, we will understand better those).

I need two words which emphasize the difference between A often causes or predicts B and A must cause B.

Comment: A *law*, as in the law of gravity, the law of thermodynamics*?

Comment: Interesting thought!  I'd prefer an adjective. I also don't really see laws as that absolute, especially because I definitely broke the law on my way to work this morning.

Comment: you need a word that is more certain than law?

Comment: @WeylandYutani I need an adjective. Besides, Ohm's Law is a guideline, Hooke's Law is a guideline, Bernoulli's Law is a guideline.

Comment: so you need a adjective that is certain

Comment: @WeylandYutani Yes? I'm not sure that certain vs predictive emphasizes the difference I'm looking for, but perhaps I need to wrap my head around it more.

Comment: I guess a verb would work as well.

Comment: @WeylandYutani I think "certain" **is** the appropriate adjective...

Comment: *A causes B* covers the 100% case just fine. Now you just need a word to contrast with *cause* for the other case. Unfortunately, there are quite a list of these with rather subtle differences in a technical setting. I don't think you want some variation on the theme (ie causal factor), you want something different from *cause*. If you are trying to inculcate an awareness of this distinction, you could use *correlation*, with the proviso that there is a *sensu stricto* usage and a *sensu lato* usage, and that this is very much the latter one.

Comment: inevitable, inevitably

Comment: Also invariably.  This contrasts rather well with a probability.

Comment: How about _A guarantees B_ ? In philosophy and logic the relevant phrase would be that _A is a sufficient condition for B_.

Comment: @SteveLovell So many great words, and nobody to submit an answer for voting...

Answer (score 3):

There are some good suggestions in the comments, which I'm going to pick from in my answer. All definitions from Merriam-Webster unless otherwise noted.

**A guarantees B**
[*Guarantee*: an assurance for the fulfillment of a condition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guarantee)

**A invariably causes B**
[*Invariably*: on every occasion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invariably)

**A makes B certain / A makes B certain to occur**
[*Certain*: (3a) dependable, reliable - (a certain remedy for the disease)

(3b) known or proved to be true : indisputable (it is certain that we exist)

(4a) inevitable (the certain advance of age)

(4b) incapable of failing : destined - used with a following infinitive (she is certain to do well)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/certain)

**A necessitates B**
[*Necessitate*: to make necessary, to force or compel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/necessitate)

**A is sufficient for B / A is a sufficient condition for B**
[*Sufficient Condition*: a state of affairs whose existence assures the existence of another state of affairs.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sufficient%20condition) Note: This is common wording amongst philosophers, mathematicians and logicians, but it could sound odd in other contexts.

**B is necessary for A / B is a necessary condition for A**
[*Necessary Condition*: a proposition whose falsity assures the falsity of another.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/necessary%20condition) Note: This is common wording amongst philosophers, mathematicians and logicians, but it could sound odd in other contexts.

I can't think of many options for cases when the causal relationship is specifically probabilistic. Again, philosophers have a word for it:

**A probabilifies B**
[*Probabilify*: to make probable, give probability to](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/probabilify) (Oxford Living Dictionaries)

Comment: I hadn't included "certain" initially as the you'd have to structure the sentence differently, but it felt like it ought to be included ... and so now is. Hat-Tip to @WeylandYutani.

Comment: Also a Hat-Tip to @Xanne for "invariably".

Answer (score 0):

A often causes or predicts B is **theoretical**, a **premise**.

> - [**theoretical**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/theoretical) - (adj)  "based on theory."
> - [**premise**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/premise) (noun) "A proposition upon which an argument is based or from which a conclusion is drawn."

A must cause B is **mathematical**.

> - [**mathematical**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mathematical) - (adj) "rigorously exact, precise, certain."

Comment: Theory is far more certain than hypothesis or even Truth to scientists. Interesting suggestions though...